# How can I replace commas per newlines, but only if they are not between brackets?

Tags: bash, sed

I was wondering if you could help me with a replacement script im trying here...

I've got something like this:

```
aaaaaa,aaaaa,aaaaa,aaaa,aaaaa,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaaa,aaa
aaaa,aaaaa,aaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaa[1,2], aaaaaaaa[5,6], aaaa,aaaaaaa
```

and want to order the file to get something like:

```
aaaaaa,
aaa,
aaaaa,
aaaaa[1,2],
aaaaaaaa[5,6],
aaaaa,
aaaaaaaa,
aaaa
```

I've tried replacing `,` with line-breaks, but it separates the `[n,n]` blocks, too.

Also tried replacing `,[^0-9]` with line-breaks, but I loose the first char after the comma.

I've been trying sed, but I'm not sure how this would look like.

I've added a sample of the file:

```
x0.fieldB [1,2] ,x5.fieldC ,x0.fieldX ,x0.fieldA
(x0.fieldE [1,5] = x2.fieldZ) ) AND (x0.fieldG [1,2] = x3.fieldT ) )
```

and should get something like this:

```
x0.fieldB [1,2] ,
x5.fieldC ,
x0.fieldX ,
x0.fieldA (x0.fieldE [1,5] = x2.fieldZ) ) AND (x0.fieldG [1,2] = x3.fieldT ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to not lose that digit, you need to capture it with (escaped) parenthesis, and then substitute it with `\1` as follows:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\),/\1\n/g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix: Replace , and <]>, with enters.

Comment: sed 's/\([^0-9]\),/\1\n/g' yourfile  worked for me
thanks all for your time

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that works in your case:

```
sed -e 's;\([A-Za-z \t]\),;\1,\n;g' -e 's;],;],\n;g'
```

What it does is replaces comma after any character in ranges A-Z or a-z, or a whitespace. And then replaces all `],` occurrences. Seems to do exactly what you want. I am not a `regexp` or `sed` expert and most likely this can be written much better, so don't blame me :-)